# JSF validator method results in duplicate FacesMessage shown in p:messages

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two PrimeFaces `p:calendar` components, one representing a begin and the other representing an end date.

I want to run a validator method now whenever one of them changes.

Here's the end date component:

```
                <p:calendar id="end-date"
                            widgetVar="testEndDate"
                            value="#{testManager.endDate}"
                            mindate="#{testManager.minEndDate}"
                            maxdate="#{testManager.maxEndDate}"
                            validator="#{testManager.validateEndDate}">
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="begin-date msgs" global="false" />
                </p:calendar>
```

Here's the validator method code:

```
@Override
public void validateEndDate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)throws ValidatorException
{
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".validateEndDate()!");

    Date beginDate = this.getBeginDate();
    Date endDate = (Date)value;

    if ( endDate != null && endDate.getTime() <= beginDate.getTime() )
    {
        System.out.println("End date less than or equal to begin date!");

        // this.setValidated( false );
        //
        // throw new ValidatorException( JsfUtil.getValidationErrorFacesMessage( "common.validator.validTo.message" ) );
        context.addMessage(null, JsfUtil.getValidationErrorFacesMessage("common.validator.validTo.message"));
    }

    List < FacesMessage > messages = context.getMessageList();

    if ( !messages.isEmpty() )
    {
        System.out.println("Faces messages list not empty! Size = " + messages.size());

        this.setValidated(false);

        throw new ValidatorException(messages);
    }

    this.setValidated(true);
}
```

Here's what I do:

- Show the dialog via command button.
- Click into the empty **end** date calendar input, which pops up the calendar.
- Click on the 22 (same date as the begin date).

The code basically works, at least according to the console output:

```
INFO: DefaultValidatingBeginEndDateChecker.validateEndDate()!
INFO: End date less than or equal to begin date!
INFO: Faces messages list not empty! Size = 1
```

However, this shows the same `FacesMessage` **twice** on the UI:

[image]

As you can see, the output doesn't match what the validator method is saying.

Does anyone know what's going on/wrong and how to fix this? (Also note the outcommented code showing the working solution, but I need to know why this isn't working, because I have another more complex validator which has 1+ ifs which is supposed to show more than one message...).

Comment: maybe it's becuase `msgs` is being called twice? when you're selecting a date on `end-date`, the statement `update="begin-date msgs"` refreshes the `msgs` and `begin-date` which also refreshes the `msgs` element?

Comment: `msgs` doesn't seem to be updated twice. The console output posted is complete, starting from when the dialog is shown. The begin date gets a default of today, so no calendar `dateSelect` is necessary for the begin date.

Comment: Wow, someone edited the question to change the formatting of the Java code. Restored. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works is to collect the faces messages in an own list:

```
    List<FacesMessage> messages = new ArrayList<FacesMessage>();

    if ( endDate != null && endDate.getTime() <= beginDate.getTime() )
    {
        System.out.println( "End date less than or equal to begin date!" );

        // context.addMessage( null, JsfUtil.getValidationErrorFacesMessage( "common.validator.validTo.message" ) );
        messages.add( JsfUtil.getValidationErrorFacesMessage( "common.validator.validTo.message" ) );
    }

    // ... more ifs

    if ( !messages.isEmpty() )
    {
        System.out.println( "Faces messages list not empty! Size = " + messages.size() );

        this.setValidated( false );

        throw new ValidatorException( messages );
    }

    this.setValidated( true );
```

Doh.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is an expected behaviour. Look suspiciously at the following two lines of code:

1. `context.addMessage(null, JsfUtil.getValidationErrorFacesMessage("common.validator.validTo.message"));` and
2. `throw new ValidatorException(messages);`.

Think what they do. The first line adds a message to the current context and the second one throws an exception, instructing JSF that validation has failed, and this in turn adds your list of exceptions to the current context as well.

So, the solution is straightforward: remove the redundant `context.addMessage(null, JsfUtil.getValidationErrorFacesMessage("common.validator.validTo.message"));` line and replace your `throws` clause for `throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(JsfUtil.getValidationErrorFacesMessage("common.validator.validTo.message")));`.

Comment: The problem is, that I have another validator, which is supposed to show 1 or 2 messages, that is each date might collide with the local other date, but also with an outer constraining date, so there will be in effect another if in the code. I posted the short version first. As you can see from the outcommented three lines, the solution you present was known to me, but the question was rather "WHY does the variant above show more than the ones in the list and how do you get around this?" (if I can't get it done with the easy validator, there' no need to try the more complex one, you know...).